# BCRYPTJS: returning same hash for different passwords

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I didn't find anyone with similar problem on google, what happens is no matter the password user inputs it returns hash as if that is correct password, but you can input anything and it will still return same hashed password of that mail when it's found in database.

For example:

Password input: `asd`

bcrypt: `$2a$12$EkucFAxlupmAzec1CDnBmuYugwAO4cXj.5bt/thg8l/dG0JDhMScm`

Password input: `astastas`

bcrypt: `$2a$12$EkucFAxlupmAzec1CDnBmuYugwAO4cXj.5bt/thg8l/dG0JDhMScm`

code:

```
    exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;

        Users.findOne({ email: email }).then(result => {
            if (!result) {
                throw new Error('No user with that email');
            }
            else if (crypt.compare(password, result.password)) {
                const token = jwebtoken.sign({ email: result.email },
                    'thisisatokenyoucantfake', { expiresIn: '1h' });

                res.status(200).json({ token: token });
                console.log(password);
                console.log(result.password);
            } else {
                throw new Error('No user');
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
```

`mongodb` atlas is used for storing hashed passwords, encrypt length is **12**.

if anyone needs solution:

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    Users.findOne({ email: email }).then(result => {
        if (!result) {
            throw new Error('No user with that email');
        } else {
            return crypt.compare(password, result.password);
        }
    }).then(result => {
        if (result) {
            const token = jwebtoken.sign({ email: result.email },
                'thisisatokenyoucantfake', { expiresIn: '1h' });

            res.status(200).json({ token: token });
        } else {
            throw new Error('Wrong password');
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Post the code where you encrypt the password.

Comment: Not related to your question but using `async/await` instead of `Promise.then()`s would make your code much easier to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[bcrypt.compare](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/blob/master/bcrypt.js#L181) is *asynchronous* - it returns a promise. Your if statement will always return true because a promise is a truthy value. You need to resolve the promise using either `await` or `.then()` to get the resulting boolean.

Also you're logging the input plaintext password and the stored hash - the stored hash *should* always be the same as that's the point.